# How to use word in parentheses

Tags: grammar

I wrote a sentence:

> Figure 6(top) shows that....... while figure 6(bottom) shows....

1. Does this sentence look grammatically clear with using parentheses?
2. Do I have to leave a space after number 6, before ()?

Comment: 1. This is not grammar, it is punctuation. 2. Yes, it is quite clear (assuming that "top" and "bottom" refer to these locations within Fig 6). 3. Yes, you need spaces before the parentheses.

Comment: Side question: Why so many dots? Three will do the trick...

Comment: @AmirA.Shabani -- He's getting a little dotty ...........

Answer (score -1):

## The Grammar of Parentheses

You are right, in a way. Parentheses require spaces before/after the preceding and succeeding words. Word itself, in some 365 editions, throws an error in grammar relating to your issue:

> **Consider adding a space before punctuation**
>
> Instead of:
>
> The book(mentioned on chap. 9)is also on sale
>
> Consider:
>
> The book (mentioned on chap. 9) is also on sale

### Other versions of Word:

Other versions of Word may throw a spelling error instead of a grammatical one.

## Exceptions

When indicating gender difference, their is no need to add a space after the parentheses but add a space after the preceding word as normal:

> "If (s)he is available to attend, please fill out the slip below."